# Sorting an array of structs using qsort

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, qsort

I am new to C, so I apologize if there are any obvious errors. I want to sort this list in alphabetical order using `qsort`. I came up with this, but my sort function doesn't return anything for some reason. No error, it's just blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// struct person with 3 fields
struct People {
    char* name;
    char age;
};
static int myCompare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
 
    // setting up rules for comparison
    return strcmp(*(const char**)a, *(const char**)b);
}
// Function to sort the array
void sort(const char* arr[], int n)
{
    // calling qsort function to sort the array
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(const char*), myCompare);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0, n = 17;

    struct People arr[n];

    // Make people list
    arr[0].name = "Bell";
    arr[0].age = 20;

    arr[1].name = "Tan";
    arr[1].age = 31;

    arr[2].name = "Jones";
    arr[2].age = 19;

    // Sort the given names
    sort(arr, n);

    // Print the sorted names
    printf("\nSorted array is\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d: %s \n", i, arr[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(const char*)` needs to be `sizeof(struct People)` and you need to cast to the struct type in the compare function. The signature for `sort` is also incorrect, you're passing an array of People, not strings.

Comment: How do I pass just strings instead because I need to sort the array but it contains both string and integers? Would it be sort(string arr[], int n) then?

Comment: You can sort the array based on the string inside each struct, but you do not have an array of strings. If you did then how would you map them back to the struct with the other data? You also only want to pass the actual number of items you've filled in as the size and you only want to print the items you've filled in as well. You need turn up the compiler warnings and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/ze13n3ExT

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues. I have the strong impression you have tried to blindly adapt some code that was supposed to sort pointers to `char*` without understanding the basics.

You want this, explanations in the comments:

```
static int myCompare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
  return strcmp(((struct People *)a)->name, ((struct People*)b)->name);
}

void sort(struct People arr[], int n)              // you want to sort an array
                                                   // of struct People
{
  // calling qsort function to sort the array
  qsort(arr, n, sizeof(struct People), myCompare); // the size of your elements is
                                                   // sizeof(struct People), 
                                                   // not size of (char*)
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0, n = 3;          // you don't have 17 elements, you only have 3
                             // With the original value 17 you would sort
                             // 17 elements, but your array contains
                             // only 3 elements, the other 14 ones
                             // are uninitialized

  struct People arr[n];

  // Make people list
  arr[0].name = "Bell";
  arr[0].age = 20;

  arr[1].name = "Tan";
  arr[1].age = 31;

  arr[2].name = "Jones";
  arr[2].age = 19;

  // Sort the given names
  sort(arr, n);

  // Print the sorted names
  printf("\nSorted array is\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d: %s \n", i, arr[i].name);   // you want to print the name,
                                           // not a struct People

  return 0;
}
```

Explanation for `((struct People *)a)->name` in `myCompare`.

The comparision function has 3 parametes,the first and the second ones are pointers to the elements to be compared, the third one is the size of an element.

`(struct People *)a)` casts the void pointer `a` to a pointer to `struct People`. The `->` operator accesses the `name` field.

If you want to sort by age all you need to to is replace

```
strcmp(((struct People *)a)->name, ((struct People*)b)->name)
```

with

```
((struct People *)a)->age < ((struct People*)b)->age
```